# Branched flow of light - qualitative explanation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, interference, diffraction

Recently a Nature paper [Observation of branched flow of light](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2376-8) shows observation of "branched flow" of a narrow laser beam hitting onto a well-controlled, stable bubble. The condition required is to have a suitable correlation length of the bubble:

[image]

*(A very nice video regarding this: [nature video: The laser show in a soap bubble](https://youtu.be/UNCNp1tBqKY))*

We know in free-space light propagates in straight lines (ray optics approximation), or diffract into bundles (wave optics). In the paper they offer a view from the Schrödinger's equation, with wave propagation simulations.

**My understandings**:

- Mathematically Schrödinger's equation is similar to the [paraxial Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation). Thus a scalar field theory should be sufficient.
- [Path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is another way to describe Schrödinger's equation, and these "branched flow" are sort of "paths". A path integral approach would also suffice.

**Question**

Are there any other easier, more intuitive ways to qualitatively explain this "branched flow" phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really remarkable about "branched flow" of light.  A collimated beam traversing a medium with nonuniformities will spread into branched channels whether we like it or not.  Treating the beam as a bundle of rays, it is easy to see that each ray will encounter a slightly different set of refractive index variations, or other such variations, and will follow a slightly different path form the other rays.  The farther a ray propagates, the more different will be the series of variations it encounters, compared to those of the other rays.  There will be a relatively few paths that correspond to "quasi-stationary" paths, where small deviations from the path are effectively damped out.  Those quasi-stationary paths are the almost-discrete "branches" seen in the photo.  But if the photo were examined very closely it would be evident that between the bright "branches" there are still many, many other paths with less density.  So, the pattern of branches is vaguely analogous to a caustic pattern: entirely deterministic, and controlled by the distribution of nonuniformities in the medium.